# Is it okay to remote the .git from tensorflow?

Tags: git, github, tensorflow, bazel

I have a project that uses openCV and tensorflow. I cloned the tensorflow source and built a few files within the source, such as label_image and image_retrain. In the future, I plan to use the code from label_image and merge it with some openCV code, and build it from there (do I need to build it?). Anyway, when I upload my project to github and include the tensorflow folder (which I would like to change), the folder gets uploaded as a greyed out submodule because the .git file in the tensorflow folder points to the tensorflow source on github. Can I safely remove this so that I can upload the folder to my github, and can I do so without compromising future bazel builds?

Comment: Yes, no problem. Git is only to manage version control. If you do not care about the TF version, you can remove the Git folders. Beware that it will make it hard to upgrade TF in the future... A Git sub module is really the best way to go.

Comment: @EricPlaton as someone who hasn't used a submodule before, will this allow me to alter and build on the side without conflicts with future TF versions, or would making my own branch be best?

Comment: Sub-modules are best when the target module (TF here) is just a dependency that you will not modify. A sub-module specifies a repository and a commit hash, so you know what exact version your code depends on, and you can control that version (i.e. upgrade when you want). If you need to modify the code, a sub-module may get in the way when upgrading, etc.---still feasible (not recommended).

Comment: @EricPlaton if I checkout a new branch and then push that to my new repository, will my branch still be considered a submodule? If I'm really working off of a modified tensorflow, is having my own branch without having it as a submodule the way to go?

Comment: What you are asking is quite ambiguous. Hard for me to give an answer. A branch and a sub module are two unrelated features in Git. A branch on your repository can specify using a specific branch of a sub module. Anyway, we are drifting away. If you have different questions to ask, please open new questions. The community will be happy to address all of them in a tidier way than here :-)

Answer (score 1):

As far as Bazel is concerned, it doesn't care about your sub-directory being a git directory or just vendoring so you should be safe to remove the .git directory of TensorFlow and remove tensorflow directory from the list of git submodules (see your `.gitmodules` file)

Comment: Thanks. While I have you here, if I include the code from label_image.py (which I built with bazel) in another program, say example.py, do I have to build this with bazel as well?

Comment: Technically there is no need to use Bazel for Python import but you have to add the good import path. The best is probably to add the runfiles directory of a py_binary (so bazel-bin/pkg/label.runfiles) to your Python import path